# ARCore: ImageAnalysis.setAnalyzer from CameraX API not working with ARFragment

Tags: java, android, arcore, android-camerax

Initially, I managed to make the `ImageAnalyis.setAnalysis` work. It returned me an `ImageProxy` object.

This was without the `ArFragment` in `XML` file.

I need to integrate an `ARFragment`, which is a requirement. I also need to make use of `ImageAnalyis.setAnalysis` to generate an `ImageProxy` object.

```
ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis =
                        new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                                //.setTargetResolution(new Size(1280, 720))
                                .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                                .build();


                imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(Runnable::run, new ImageAnalysis.Analyzer() {
                    @SuppressLint("UnsafeExperimentalUsageError")
                    @Override
                    public void analyze(@NonNull ImageProxy image) {
                        Log.d("Image","Generate"); //This doesn't get called ARfragment is present in the XML file


                       
                        //clear stream for next image
                        image.close();
                    }
                });
```

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/arSceneView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android:id="@+id/viewFinder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/boundingBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

How can I fix this? Is there any way?